# Not able to see apex class in the org in salesforce

Tags: apex, process-builder, class

I wrote an apex class which is visible in process builder but not in the org.

I created new process in process builder. Steps as follows:

1. Click On Immediate Action -> Action Type->Select Apex from drop down.
2. Give a name to Action
3. In Apex Class -> Select one Apex Class.
4. Now here in Apex Class picklist I can see one Entry or class name .This class does exist.

When I try to see this class in the org under Apex Classes, it doesn't exist.

Why is that so? My guesses:

1. The class I am seeing in process builder  is not an apex class . It might be some custom setting or trigger etc.
2. I don't have access to the class .somehow I am seeing this in builder but not available in the org as it's deleted.
3. Its deleted.
4. Its a bug.

I checked workbench, recycle bin, and custom setting but found nothing.

What else could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Try running a SOQL query directly from the Developer Console to try and find it. E.g. `Select Id from ApexClass where Name = 'SuperSimpleInvocable'`. In my process builder immediate action the Apex Class name appeared as "DB__SuperSimpleInvocable". I needed to remove the `DB__` namespace prefix as that isn't part of the ApexClass name but rather a packaging artifact.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I Tried this but didnt got the desired result there is no class with that name.

Comment: what is the class name in question? It might be that your profile doesn't have access to the class - [How Does Apex Class Security Work?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_package_security.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 2):

Check your list view settings. You are most likely filtering the classes in the list by default

[image]

If it does not Say "All" or has an "Edit View" link then it is not set to the default "All" list that shows everything. Either change the selected view or click edit to review the current filters

Comment: And, annoyingly, saleforce doesn't remember the last list view you were on in this screen. And, All goes away once you create a view, so then you have to create a new All view.

Comment: @sfdcfox - If you delete all of the user created views All suddenly comes back...It does not like to play with others I guess

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, but the setup screens that can't remember which view you were last on are some of my biggest pet peeves as a person who spends like 90% of their time in setup.

Comment: @sfdcfox Pet peeves -> Breadcrumbs -> Take be back to something I was on days ago and not where I just came from....lol

Comment: Hi Eric I am looking at.    View All setting only